# Customizing titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I've read through section 2 and 3 of `titlesec`'s package documentation, and unfortunately I find it extremely cryptic, so I've given up trying to come to terms with it. Please bear with me as I'm just posting an example of how I want my `\section` headings to look.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section{My first section}
Here is the content of my first section.\\

% Below how I want it to look
\noindent {\large{\textbf{1. My first section}}}\\
Here is the content of my first section.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
Some test text here.

\end{document}
```

An image before the changes:

[image]

an image after the changes:

[image]

#### Explanation of the code:

Take the default settings for `\section`:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

change `\Large` to `\large`, add a period after `\thesection`, change `1em` (the default separation between number and title) to `0.5em` (or to the desired value), and reduce the length in the fourth argument of `\titlespacing*`.

By the way, and not related, to the question, `\large` (and the other font size switches also) doesn't take arguments; instead of `\large{<text>}` you should use `{\large <text>}` (the braces just in case grouping is required).